# Are morphemes commonly found at the end of words considered suffixes?

Tags: suffixes, morphology, derivational-morphology, affixes

Are morphemes commonly found at the end of words considered suffixes?

**For example:** "erate", found at the end of words like *accelerate, operate, refrigerate, considerate, nonliterate,* etc.

I am a bit unsure as to the full scope of affixes, whether they have to carry a concrete meaning with them, or if they could be common components of words with a more vague semantics.

Also, some affixes, if they are affixes, seem to carry a functional meaning, like "converting" a root from one word class to another, like "*sentient*" to "*sentience*". Here, *ience/ence* is the "converter", but is it considered a suffix, a morpheme, neither or both?

I also recognize that *ient/ent* is the same as *ience/ence*, only regarding adjectives.

So, let's get back to the "erate" thing. Common found combination of letters, is it a morpheme, affix, neither or both? Is it just common, or is it functional, like *ience/ence*, or does it carry a concise meaning, making it simply a suffix? Perhaps it's meaning is just "of or pertaining to a verb/adjective". And that's something I noticed, the pronunciation of "erate" differs whether it is a verb or an adjective.

So yeah, how does it all work?

Comment: What does your research show?

Comment: https://www.dictionary.com/e/what-are-prefixes-and-suffixes/ This doesn't say anything about morphology,

Comment: One could start by quoting from [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/morpheme). Then one could check a reasonably comprehensive list of suffixes, say at [Learnthat.org](https://www.learnthat.org/pages/view/suffix.html). This states that -ate, not -erate, is a suffix, with two functions.

Comment: If it was a morpheme it *might* be a suffix, but you've no evidence that "-erate" is a [morpheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morpheme). A common group of letters is not necessarily a morpheme, and a morpheme at the end of a word is not always a suffix (e.g. "cut" in "uncut" is not a suffix despite the word comprising the morphemes "un" and "cut".) I suggest reading the Wikipedia article on morphemes.

Answer (score -1):

Suffixes and prefixes are examples of affixes. And which in turn are examples of morphemes. These in turn are defined as the smallest unit of lexical sense.

For example the suffix 's' is a morpheme which denotes plurality.

However your 'affix' -erate seems to lack the quality of sense. What does it mean when affixed to another morpheme? I would suggest that it does not have any sense amd so is not a morpheme. Similarly, just becaise 'station', 'ration' and 'operation' all share the suffix 'tion' dpes not mean that 'tion' here is a morpheme because we would have to also show what sense it would carry.

Comment: Not a great example since -tion is a morpheme with a meaning of sorts. It's not productive in English though.

Answer (score -3):

The primary suffix usage is to bond with, hold, or incite use of; therefore dependent on context it could be any of the applied uses and classifications inquired upon. The affix classification applies within the confines of particular words and their implied use within syntaxes structures.

Accel-erate: inciting accel as a verb perhaps adverd, bonded to accel implying meaning of accel (propelled or momentous action particularly in a direction opposed to the initial point), or in a present tense but post tense held attribute or value and "holding" of accel; "it will accelerate... you accelerate "verb or adverb", or simply "it is an accelerate function of "said implement or noun".

In other use it may be found to fall outside the prescribed use but still be referred to and classified as the prior definition of suffix exemplified by the word: venerate

Ven being fairly vague but attributed to having or containing within, being of, expressing such, or being causal for and of:
Venn diagram (lol not a real example)
Vengeance
Vernacular
Venture
Vent
Vendor

Wherein we can see that VEN combined with ERATE becomes the combination of two similar meanings of prefix and suffix but together create a word which beholds:
The having or containing with or within, being of, expressing or being causal of bonding, with holding, or inciting use of; in this example the seemingly similar meanings compound each others meaning and become: having great reverence or regard for.

Comment: -erate is not a suffix in Latin or English. It's a misanalysis based on a few words that happen to have -er- as part of a previous suffix or root before the final suffix -ate. In the case of accelerate, it is to be broken down etymologically as ac-celer-ate. The suffix is -ate and it is found in other words, like participate.

Comment: The "ven" morpheme you have proposed does nor exist and those words are not related to each other. In fact, you managed to find words that aren't even incidentally related. The Latin nouns and verbs are vindicantia (from vim + dico = speak with force), vernacularis (from verna = native), ventura (participle of venio = come), ventus (= wind), venditor (from venum + dare = give for sale).